# Change x axis origin to a value (not zero) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on generating a tornado plot in R. I am using `ggplot2` package with code like the following:

```
dat <- structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("# of nodes needed", 
"# of nodes owned", "cost per node"), class = "factor"), Level = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("high", "low"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(-275, -550, -50, 825, 275, 450)), .Names = c("variable", 
"Level", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dat, aes(fill=Level,variable,value )) +
    geom_bar(position = 'identity',stat = 'identity') + coord_flip()
```

I am curious as to how to change x-axis origin. Right now, the origin is automatically set to zero, and I want to be able to change it to a variable specified numeric value.

Comment: Did you try `?xlim`?

Comment: When using xlim I get error: discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: Try to make your example reproducible. Currently, I have no idea what is in 'result'.

Comment: Added in result code, it is a data frame calling cells in an example excel sheet i created

Comment: Please read this: [reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The easiest way is to copy-paste the output of `dput(dat)` to your question.

Comment: Added output to question

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with the current output? What do you mean with 'change x-axis origin to a value'? What is your expected output? (If it's hard to explain, you may also past an image of a hand-drawn sketch/chart).

Comment: Right now the x-axis origin is 0, but I want it to be a value in 'result' (in this case, output or $550)

Comment: Maybe you can change the labels?

Comment: is `dat$value2 <- dat$value - 550 ; ggplot(dat, aes(fill=Level,variable,value2 )) + geom_bar(position = 'identity',stat = 'identity') + coord_flip()` closer to what you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer but I was just solving a similar problem. I used `limits`and `expand` in `scale_x_continuous`.

So I guess for you it would look something like this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(fill=Level,variable,value )) +
geom_bar(position = 'identity',stat = 'identity') + 
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2, 32), expand = c(0, 0))
```

except making `limits = c(2,32)` be whatever you want the limits of the x axis to be. Means you have to set this manually, but the best work around I came up with doing the same thing.